# How are spend/out/in proofs sent to verifiers?

Tags: transaction-data

I am currently reading the Zero to Monero book, section 8.1.2/8.1.3/8.1.4. I am unable to understand how these proofs work. Each section talks about generating a signature, however, the tx structure does not store them in the MG field (or do they?). So how can the verifiers know about these proofs?

Comment: These are proofs you make after a transaction has been added to the blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use email, or a USB stick, FTP, pastebin sites... It doesn't matter how you send that information, as long as it arrives verbatim.

The wallet saves the proofs as binary by default, but if you're going to transfer that data via text protocols which aren't 8 bit clean, you can switch it to ASCII export (using "set export-format ascii" in monero-wallet-cli).

These proofs should not be in the transactions, otherwise they'd necessarily be public, which would defeat the purpose of being private by default while being to prove particular things to a particular party.